# use < and > in 'if' statement with TextViews

Tags: java, android

I have two TextViews that displays numbers from 1-6, I need to make a if statement thats like this:

```
if (x < y)
do this
else
do ths
```

But it says that I cant use < and > for TextViews so I guess I have to make them into "int".
How do I do that?

Comment: nobody will understand what is your problem, post some sample code. Also the <and> operator is &&

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `hashCode()` method.

```
if (x.getText().toString().hashCode() < y.getText().toString().hashCode())
do this
else
do this
```

You should have to use `Integer.parseInt()` method to parse the number.

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this to get intger of textview

```
Integer.parseInt(tv1.getText().toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<` and `>` operators in Java only work for numeric types and boxed numeric types.  A `TextView` is most certainly not one of these.

There are ways to turn the *contents* of a text view into a number.

Indeed there are many different ways to do this, starting with parsing the `TextView`s content string as an integer or floating point, through taking the string's length, or its X or Y coordinate ... or its identity hashcode!

But the bottom line is that *you* have to write the code to do the conversion.  Java won't try to guess which of the many possibilities that you might mean.

Comment: Ok, is it possible to use something else in XML to diplay numbers?

Comment: Your comment doesn't make sense.  You don't use '<' or '>' in XML to "display" numbers.  And your question isn't even about XML.

Comment: I meant that I should use something else instead of TextView when making the layout in XML.

Answer (score 0):

x=Integer.parseInt(xTextView.getText().toString()) do similarly for yTextView. So that u will get 2 integers which u can compare

Answer (score 0):

Use Integer.parseInt(tv1.getText().toString()) to convert your textview object's text to integer. Do this for all 6 values and assign them to integer variables.

You may now compare these integer variables to work further.